# What is the equation describing earth's orbit around the sun in 3 dimensional space?

Tags: geometry, physics, conic-sections, 3d, mathematical-astronomy

I'm trying to draw a 2d ellipse in 3d space, which describes earth's orbit around the sun. such as [image of a 2d ellipse in 3d space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFPjD.jpg) or the [same image but different perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKyN6.jpg). I'd like to be able to get the z y x coordinates of the planet at any give time. What would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: If I am correct, the revolution of the earth around the sun takes place on a plane; so you may need only 2 coordinates.

Comment: You may have a look at stuuf such as " derivation of Kepler's laws".

Comment: In fact the most useful coordinates in the plane are polar, with the substitution $u=1/r$.

Comment: @VinceVickler because i intend on adding other planets too, which have different orbital planes.

Comment: You could write the ellipse in the x-y plane (something like $x^2/a^2 + y^2 / b^2 = 1$ and then apply a rotation matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) to the coordinates.

Comment: @Blitzer How should i go about choosing the axis around which to rotate the equation? I want the equation to closely resemble NASA's calculated Ephemeris.

Comment: @N1c0z: Equation of curve depends on origin location and axes directions, equation $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ is correct for some origin and axes. If one knows 3 points of ellipse in some other coordinate system, one can restore ellipse plane. If one knows 5 points of ellipse, one can restore ellipse equation.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach may well depends on what your specific use case is.

Typically you need two things: a description of an ellipse in a plane, and a relationship between that orbital plane and the 3d coordinate system.

Since the ellipse will have the sun as a focus, you might go with a description in terms of polar coordinates. So you would have a function $r(\theta)$ to describe the distance from the sun as a function of angle. Then you could combine the conversion from polar coordinates into Cartesian coordinates with the switch from 2d to 3d and do both at the same time.

$$
\overrightarrow x(\theta)=r(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta)\cdot\overrightarrow v_1+r(\theta)\cdot\sin(\theta)\cdot\overrightarrow v_2
$$

where $\overrightarrow v_{1,2}$ would be two orthogonal 3d unit vectors spanning your orbital plane. They would represent the axes of your 2d coordinate system in terms of 3d coordinates. A third vector $\overrightarrow v_3$ orthogonal to both of these would make that coordinate system (or vector space basis) complete but won't be needed for orbital positions.

Depending on how your orbits are given (i.e. which orbital elements) different methods would be used to compute the basis vectors of the coordinate system for a specific celestial body as well as the details of the parametric equations. For example you might pick $\theta=0$ to represent the perihelion position. That would make the polar formula symmetric and thus a bit easier, and for 3d it's typically as good a choice as any.

Keep in mind with the parametric description using angle that bodies on elliptical and not circular orbits don't cover equal angle in equal time. So an animation with constant change of angle would not correctly represent physical speed.